# Error 401 (Unauthenticated) when making a request to Google Docs API

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to request the contents of a Google doc (that I own) using the Google Docs API and the contents would be read to a website. I'm making the following request in Postman:

```
GET https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/{documentId}?key=API_KEY
```

where the API_KEY is a key created in Google developer dashboard and is not restricted for now. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
    {
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

I have made the doc public (read-access without signing in) and enabled the Docs API in the Google developer dashboard. Further, the dashboard is registering these (failing) requests, so something is going through.The answer is probably in the error message, but to me "or other valid authentication credential" means the API key that I'm already using.

I'm asking for advice on how to make this request successfully without needing to use OAuth or server-side code.

Comment: Have you looked at: https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/first-app and https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/access-google-drive-rest-apis-using-oauth2-postman-haris-saleem

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround answer to my problem, although it didn't solve the problem with the Docs API. I decided to request the text data from a Google Sheet instead, which works fine with

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/documentId?key=API_KEY
```

when the sheet is public and read-only.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can open the doc programatically using a service account. You need to "share" the doc with the service account email.

Instructions on creating a service account and reading a Google doc: https://www.futurice.com/blog/read-goog-doc-using-service-account